# Will there be elementary OS 5.0

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there a elementary OS 5.0 in development? Because I would love to send some feedback! Also i would like to see hex-chat as a built in support software.

Answer (score 1):

Development for elementary 0.5 will be happening in the [*future* series on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/elementaryos/+milestone/loki+1-beta1), however currently there are no changes, only bug reports (not surprising given that elementary 0.4 was only released this month).

If you are referring to being able to install Hexchat on Loki, it can be found in AppCenter (or can be installed with `sudo apt install hexchat`). If you meant you would like to be able to request support via Hexchat, you can join the elementary IRC channel #elementary on Freenode.

Comment: Wow Elementary OS 0.4 is one month old